# How to redirect srv dns to other domain

Tags: dns, minecraft, srv

I got a domain and want people to people able to join a server for a game I'm currently running.

The server is running by a third party host. For now, I got a direct IP address and port I can connect through, but now I want others to be able to connect to a direct IP address. Now I have read about SRV records but I have only found examples where people want to connect to a server on their own host.

Is it possible to make a DNS record so people could connect by only entering `mc.scriptware.org`

How would I go and do this?

The domain is on Cloudflare and I have tried this:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6BOr.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow. Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may find better help on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can point your hostname to any IP you want.

Just create **A** record with your game server IP.

You DNS configuration should contain following entry:

```
mc.scriptware.org.   A   0.0.0.0
```

where *0.0.0.0* is your game server's real IP address.

---

**EDIT:**

After some more research I found that minecraft client supports *SRV* records.

You just have to create following DNS record:

```
_minecraft._tcp.mc  SRV  0 1 PORT mc.scriptware.org.
```

Where *PORT* is your server's port number.

---

It also may be good idea to set different name for subdomain that points to server (A record subdomain) eg. *mcsrv.scriptware.org* instead of *mc.scriptware.org*.

Without this game client probably will skip searching for *SRV* record, because *mc* subdomain exists and points to an IP address.

Comment: I know about A records, the problem by that is that it's not on the default port

Comment: If server doesn't run on default port, users have to specify port manually. DNS just points to IP addresses and has nothing to ports.